# Plotting an angle on a graph

Tags: polar-coordinates

So I know, my origin "(0,0)", my angle "theta" degrees, and the distance from the origin, "d"

Now I think I can work this out with polar coordinates, but really have no idea how to go about it. My overall goal is to work out the point that is (x,y) on this diagram.

[image: Figure 1]

Comment: Do you want to know the Cartesian coordinates of the point ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the polar coordinates $(r,\theta)$, to convert it to the Cartesian coordinates is a simple matter of trigonometry.

The $x$-coordinate is how far along the $x$-axis you are, so can be found using the formula $$x=d\cos\theta.$$
This is because, $x$ is the adjacent side and $d$ is the hypotenuse.

The $y$-coordinate is found likewise, so we have: $$y=d\sin\theta$$

Comment: Well this works oddly. You see what I'm trying to do is show the direction of an object on a map in a program. The map is in Cartesian coordinates and the direction is in degrees from North. So North, East South is 0 to 180 and North West South is 0 to -180. I was sure the formula that could solve the above problem would do this, but when I apply these, when the direction increases the line showing direction (from 0,0 to x,y) just spins in the direction the direction increasing. So if its going from 0 to 180 its going clockwise, if its decreasing, anti clockwise. This is really stumping me.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't quite understand what you are trying to do, do you mind explaining further?

Comment: Sorry I hit enter by accident, force of habit.

Comment: So what you are saying is that you want to find the polar coordinates from the Cartesian coordinates? And also, you are defining zero degrees to be North?

Comment: Yeah North = 0. I was only using the polar coordinate system, because I saw that it looked like what I wanted it to do. I'm not sure if its the right way to go about things. I just need to be able to work out the coordinates of the end point of the line so I can draw it, so that the line is always 500 and is at the angle from North. Its hard to explain. T

Comment: I worked it out. cos(θ * pi / 180 - pi / 2) * length